# how to call a pagemethod in a user control using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, pagemethods

I have a user control having a `pagemethod`.
  I want to call this pagemethod from my page using jquery's `ajax()` method?

How can I do that?

Thanks,
Syd

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have PageMethods on **user controls**. They have to be on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "/Service.asmx/Getuggestions",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: "{ text: \"" + request.term + "\", count: 10 }",
    success: function (data)
    {
    var items = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.d; i++)
        items[items.length] = { value: data.d[i].Code, label: data.d[i].Text };

    response(items);
    },
    error: HandleAjaxError
});
```

Comment: He is specifically talking about PageMethods, not webservices.

Comment: Sure - you can call the PageMethod in a similar fashion.

Comment: I think the problem is that if you have the PageMethod in the user control, and if you're trying to fire it from JS embedded by that user control, you have no sensible value to put in "url". You can put the page name in there, but that's not going to get you to the user control's "page method", because it's not there, it's in the user control. I think you have to use a web service to get around that. Unless someone knows how to make it work... which is what the original question was.

Answer (score 0):

A page method must be static and public , it also need to be decorated with the WebMethod attribute, for example:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
    public static void PageMethod(int Parameter)
```